# Stacking a Bar Graph and Line Graph in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

currently I wish to stack both a bar graph and line graph on top of each other.

The bar graph shows the performance of participants on a test (1-100) across different age groups (labelled KS1, KS2, KS3, 20-39 etc.) This means the y axis is their score (the variable is called "Score" and is set to a Factor) and the x axis is their age category (which is a variable called "AgeGroup" and is set to a Factor).

I wish to show a line graph on top of this bar graph directly which shows the test score across each individual age. I have another variable which states their specific age which is called "AgeSpecific" and is set to a Numeric. Therefore, the line graph will have Score in the y axis AgeSpecific in the x axis.

Below is my code for the bar graph, but I am not sure how to implement this line graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

TestAgeGraph <- ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = AgeGroup, y = Score, fill = AgeGroup)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  labs (x = "Age Group", y = "Test Score", title = "Average Stage Group Across Age Group") +
  theme_light() + geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), color = "black")

TestAgeGraph + theme (axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
                             axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
                             axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
                             plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
                             legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

I have tried to add the following line:

```
geom_line(aes(x = AgeSpecific, y = Score), color = "black")
```

This seems promising but the bars are squished on the far left of the image, as seen below and the x-axis is poorly labelled.

[Image of the Graph Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSBsf.png)

**Minimial Reproducible Example (MRE)**

```
structure(list(ID = 1:24, AgeSpecific = c(67, 5, 18, 14, 17, 
43, 14, 9, 11, 8, 19, 5, 25, 55, 45, 74, 12, 47, 48, 14, 18, 
15, 28, 28), AgeGroup = structure(c(9L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
6L), levels = c("KS1", "KS2", "KS3", "KS4", "KS5", "20-29", "30-45", 
"46-59", "60+"), class = "factor"), Score = c(74, 66, 75, 74, 
72, 81, 68, 56, 67, 78, 75, 92, 77, 78, 66, 51, 64, 73, 74, 73, 
75, 72, 73, 80)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The issue is that you mix a categorical (`AgeGroup`) and  a continuous variable (`AgeSpecific`) with apparently different ranges. Put differently Category 1 is placed at the numeric value 1, Category 2 at the numeric value 2 and so on. However, your numeric age variable ranges up to approx. 100. Hence the bars are "squished" on the left. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()`.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your responses so far, it means a lot!

I have provided an example dataset at the bottom of the original post. I hope I have provided the minimal data required correctly using the information from the page you cited @stefan. Do let me know if there are any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO there are several options to visualize your data. But as long as you want to show the individual observations or the mean per age you have to convert your `AgeGroup` `factor` into a numeric. As one approach I use `geom_rect` in the code below to show the mean values per age group, while for the lines and points I opted for means too. From a `ggplot2` point of view that's easy to achieve but requires some data wrangling steps to convert your age groups to numeric ranges. Also note, that for the `KS` groups I simply used the `min` and `max` to set the age range.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

dat <- df |>
  tidyr::separate_wider_delim(AgeGroup,
    delim = "-", too_few = "align_start",
    names = c("low", "high"),
    cols_remove = FALSE
  ) |>
  mutate(
    across(c(low, high), readr::parse_number),
  ) |>
  mutate(
    low = if_else(grepl("^KS", AgeGroup), min(AgeSpecific), low),
    high = if_else(grepl("^KS", AgeGroup), max(AgeSpecific), high),
    .by = AgeGroup
  ) |>
  tidyr::replace_na(list(high = 100))

dat_rect <- dat |>
  summarise(
    xmin = unique(low),
    xmax = unique(high),
    ymax = mean(Score),
    .by = AgeGroup
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = AgeSpecific, y = Score)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = dat_rect,
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = 0, ymax = ymax, fill = AgeGroup),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_point(color = "black", stat = "summary", fun = mean) +
  geom_line(color = "black", stat = "summary", fun = mean) +
  labs(
    x = "Age Group", y = "Test Score",
    title = "Average Stage Group Across Age Group"
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, @stefan. This has worked perfectly! Due to the xmax being 81 (the highest age in my sample), the bars for the keystages (KS1, KS2 etc.) were going all the way to 81 for some reason and I couldn't figure out why. But I was able to fix these by just manually changing the values in dat_rect myself, setting them to numeric and now everything looks perfect.

Happy to investigate this issue with the bars if you wish, but I am very satisified. Thank you :)

Comment: Hm. The only thing I can imagine which might have caused that issue (besides the max values in your KS groups are that high) would be that you are running on a "pretty" old version of `dplyr`, i.e. the `.by=` shorthand for `group_by` requires `dplyr >= 1.1.0`.

Comment: That sounds like it may be it as I am doing RStudio as part of a Psychology course, thus am instructed to update it rarely due to exams and don't use it often except in my final year except for odd projects like this. Would not be surprised if something was outdated, but am happy to get it to work regardless :)!